# If Blank is Greater than 10% of Blank - Need Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having trouble figuring out a formula. I need to find out if the number in Cell B is greater than 10% of the number in cell A. If it is, I want Cell C to say Yes.

Comment: I think I figured it out.
=IF(B1>A1*1.1,"Yes","No")

Comment: Correct.  you can also =IF(B1>A1*1.1,"Yes","") if you jsut want C to be blank if it's not Yes.

Comment: 10% (i.e. one tenth) of the value in cell A1 is `A1 * 0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Post to close. Wiki for no rep.</sub>

Per the comments:

```
=IF(B1>A1*1.1,"Yes","No")
```